# Trying to get the format that page_source from Selenium provides, but with requests

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to pull the email out of my git repo found here:

https://github.com/kyleschiess/Apex/commit/a32f5d426c8c51e41b891b0d35aa860f23c5b11b.patch

The solution via Selenium works perfectly, where:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
y = soup.find('pre')
text = y.text
email = re.findall(r'<(.+?)>',text)
email[0]
```

Gives me '38440047+kyleschiess@users.noreply.github.com'

This is because y.text is not removing the email, which is found between a '<' and '>'.

Selenium has been giving me timeout issues, so I'd rather use requests.

Now, with requests, when I do:

```
r = requests.get(patchURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
y = soup.find('p') #different format for some reason
text = y.text
email = re.findall(r'<(.+?)>',text)
email[0]
```

I get '2!'.

I found that with requests, converting a soup to text removes *everything* between a '<' and '>'.

With Selenium, anything that's not an HTML tag that lies between a '<' and a '>' is put between a '&lt;' and a '&gt;' ... So .text will not remove the email.

What can I do to get the email by using requests or urllib or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import requests
import re
url = "https://github.com/kyleschiess/Apex/commit/a32f5d426c8c51e41b891b0d35aa860f23c5b11b.patch"

text = requests.get(url).text
email = re.findall(r'<(.+?)>',text)[0]

print(email)
```

Output:

```
38440047+kyleschiess@users.noreply.github.com
```

Also, I timed it, and although the time will vary depending on your internet connection speed, the email is retrieved in about a third of a second:

```
import requests
import re
import time

start = time.time()
url = "https://github.com/kyleschiess/Apex/commit/a32f5d426c8c51e41b891b0d35aa860f23c5b11b.patch"

text = requests.get(url).text
email = re.findall(r'<(.+?)>',text)[0]

print(email)
print(time.time() - start)
```

Output:

```
38440047+kyleschiess@users.noreply.github.com
0.28287720680236816
```

Since the website is not HTML (it's actually just plain text, as far as I can tell), there's no point of using BeautifulSoup. To get the text of a website, all that's necessary is to run `requests.get(url).text`, then to get the email, you just need to filter through the text with RegEx.